# Is there any free software to easily draw time-based graph?

Tags: charts

or Excel template to draw something like below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site](http://freelancefolder.com/10-free-project-management-applications/) has a list of free project management software packages.  I think what you have there would still be considered a [Gantt Chart (see this for making them in Excel)](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/06/16/gantt-charts-project-management/).